# MultiPolygon from database

Tags: postgis, java

I would like to know how to create an instance of a Multipoint from a PostGIS database..

I do the query , then got the ResultSet named "area" , the column with MultiPolygon attributes is named "geom"
so i do the following:

```
MultiPolygon m = (MultiPolygon)area.getObject("geom");
```

xD forced cast 
Doesn't work though! :\

Anyone?
Thanks

Comment: MultiPolygon or MultiPoint?